# What is the best way to host a site with many images without it being too slow?

Tags: images, optimization

I have a friend that wants me to help them with their WordPress website that has about 150 images for their gallery. Their site is quite slow even after I optimized the images using the ImageOptim app. They are using SiteGround as their web host provider, but they are only using the StartUp package because it is the most affordable. I know that the site is slow to load because of the images, but not sure what the best approach is to try and speed it up without paying for a more expensive hosting package.

I am thinking that perhaps the best way to go about doing this would be to have them just put their images on Google Images and use that as their gallery instead, or maybe an Instagram feed like Smash Balloon.

What would you all suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Are they large image files or smallish thumbnails? If they're small, can you check if your webserver is set up for HTTP/2? (which handles multiple images on the same page more efficiently, but I'm not sure at what point it starts becoming significant)

Comment: If they're large, presumably they're not all on the screen at once? There are ways to lazily load images, so that the browser doesn't request them until they're visible.

Comment: It's probably worth making sure all your images are served by SiteGround's CDN too, if that doesn't automatically just happen. And that they aren't excessively large downloads, but again it sounds like you've already looked at that.

Comment: I will take a look at the HTTP/2 and the CDN to make certain and will ask SiteGround support as well now that I have the login info from my friend to help them out. Thanks for all your suggestions, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you remove the images to see if the website loads considerably fast. After that's done, install "Autoptimize" and enable lazy load images(You can use any lazy loading plugin but Autoptimize works perfect for me due to the wide options) and then use webp images(Great compression but still really good quality). Webp Express is a free plugin to get webp images.

Cheers

Comment: I just realized that SiteGround has their own optimizer plugin called SGOptimizer that comes with their package and it has its own lazy load setting. I guess I could use that and see if it helps at all. I will let you know.

Comment: Sure let me know. Lazy load and good compression should be enough to get the website load considerably faster. If not, let me know the website url as well.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to update you on this. Yeah, SiteGround's plugin seemed to work quite well. I am also going to have the client purchase an upgrade package or an upgrade to the free CloudFlare service.